# How to create a consecutive alphanumeric column in a QGIS attribute table?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I am trying to create a column in the attribute table such that each cell lable is a prefix (M) follwed by a unique number ie M1, M2,.. etc

Answer (score 7):

building on Joseph's answer, you might find it more useful to generate a **sortable** text field.

As this is a text field, any attempt to sort M1,M2..M10,M11,M12 will come out as

```
M1, M10, M11, M12, M2, M3 ... M9
```

If you use M0001, M0002, M0003 .. .M0012 then you have the uniqueness and can sort too.

Just modify Joseph's suggestion to

```
'M' || lpad($rownum,4,'0')
```

where 4 is the number of digits you want in the number. That will left pad the number with zeros.

You need to know the maximum number of digits you're likely to have, so if you don't know this in advance - or the data's likely to grow over time - it might not be suitable.

Comment: +1, excellent solution! Much better than what I posted! @Chris - I would recommend accepting this answer :)

Answer (score 6):

You could use the following expression (note that your column must be a **String** type):

```
'M' || $rownum
```

[image: Example image]

Comment: good suggestion. Could also make column sortable by using a format like M00001,M00002... using  `'M' || lpad($rownum,5,'0')`

Comment: @StevenKay - That's a very good point as the format you mentioned seems quite common. Consider posting it as an answer and I will upvote :)