# unable to append zero into id when updating attribute table

Tags: qgis

I want to update attribute table BID column using below line

```
($id +002)
```

but it is not adding 00 at beginning. instead adding 2,3,4,5,......
I am very beginner and this is my first try to append zero zero into features table column. 
I am somehow manage to write this

```
'0000' || ($id + 5)
```

it adding zeros but changing exceeding the id length limits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decide whether you want to have an integer or text field. If you want to do any arithemetics on the field, take integer, if you want trailing zeros, take a text field.

As a workaround, you can use an integer field, and use the field calculator to add a new, **virtual** field of type `text`, with this formula:

```
lpad( "<integer column name>" ,4,0)
```

This will make the field auto-updateable.

Comment: thanks @AndreJ is this possible to maintain 4 digit length and append '01' to every number. if the number like this you have 1, covert it to 0101.if you have 10 then covert it to 0110.

Comment: while i run your code[lpad("<integer BUILDINGID>",4,0)] it now given me null in data

Comment: if the field is named `id`, the formula should be `lpad( "id" ,4,0)`. You can select fields and functions in the right hand panel.

Comment: it didn't worked lpad("BUILDINGID",4,0)

Comment: and please tell me about my first comment

Comment: You have to sort out this one first. Have you chosen `text`? Try '0' instead of 0. You should see a preview underneath the field calculator input field. You could try also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160398/how-to-create-a-consecutive-alphanumeric-column-in-a-qgis-attribute-table to see what goes wrong for you. BTW you have to reload the attribute table to see changes.

Comment: For your second question, you might try `lpad(100+"id",4,'0')`, or use `concat('01',lpad("id",2,'0'))`.

Comment: thanks any answer for this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208702/split-all-polygon-at-once-using-python